# How to get object from nested Eager Loading Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

In query I use Nested Eager Loading:

```
$res = User::where("id", 1)->with("categories.categoryAnn.announcements")->get();
```

In result of this query I get nested collections:

```
Collection->User->categories->categoryAnn->announcements
```

How to shortly get last nested object `announcements`?

Comment: So, for this I need to make 5 nested loop, that is awful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the opposite way to get only announcements like this:

```
$announcements =  Announcement::whereHas('categoriesAnn', function($q) {
  $q->whereHas('categories, function($q) {
      $q->whereHas('user', function($q) {
          $q->where('id',1);
      });
  });
});
```

This is obviously pseudocode, because I don't know exact names of your relationships but something like this should work and you don't need any loops here.

Comment: Will check, but exactly it is so hard to make in Laravel?

Comment: And how would you do it without Eloquent? In Laravel you can also run raw query if you want or use joins if you think it's better way. Nothing stops you to do it like this.

Comment: Problem is trivial, I need to select rows from table exception rows which categories are not presented in category users.

Comment: And solution is also trival. If you want to use relations as you mentioned in other comments, you can do it like this. If you want to use raw SQL query you can also do it. It's up to you solution you will choose.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it attempting the following:

```
$categories = User::find(1)->categories()->get(); //loads the categories alone

$announcements = collection([]);

foreach(categories as $category)
{
    $announcements->push($category->categoryAnn->announcements);
}
```

The idea or assumption here is that for each categories, `categoryAnn` is one and can have `one-many` announcements.

> PS: about efficiency, I cannot really tell, but yeah, this should work.

Comment: I try to avoid additional loop, I need to create this using relations

Comment: You use only one loop here, and see, the relations are used in the loop.
eg. get all purchase orders, and for each order they have one product, and their corresponding product have many pictures. If I understood correctly, this description is similar to your question. **i need the pictures** with the example I gave I am able to retrieve all the pictures **relating** to the products.